# eufi\secure boot and auto booting into ubuntu after fresh install

Tags: 14.04, grub2, uefi, secure-boot

i performed a fresh installation of ubuntu 14.04 amd64 from a usb device as my **only** operating system, on a new hard drive device. i've tried many uefi combinations after reading [Installing Ubuntu for Single Boot with a Random Boot Mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI), and installing ubuntu in each combination but wasn't able to boot natively into ubuntu.

right now, `secure boot` and `fast boot` are enabled and disabled respectively on my machine. each time i boot, i have to launch the boot option, select *ubuntu* from the list of: os boot manager, boot from efi file, (and finally) ubuntu -- only then i am able to boot into ubuntu.

also tried [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), which produced [this log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12717652/). by examine it, i decided to try and [install grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) again, by executing `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`, but it didn't help either.

i came across the following links, but non of which helped:
[Booting into Ubuntu after Fresh Install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ( No Dual Boot ) on Acer Aspire ES1-512](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594216/booting-into-ubuntu-after-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-lts-no-dual-boot-on) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/544823/problems-installing-ubuntu-on-hp-elitebook-840

can anyone shed the light on the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following worked for me:

1. enter the bios setup, and head to the boot option -- disable *secure boot*, *fast boot*, and *pxe boot*. and set the boot mode to *legacy*. save and exit.
2. install ubuntu (i did so from a usb drive).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Boot to Ubuntu using the `ubuntu` option in your boot menu.
2. Open a Terminal window.
3. Type `sudo cp -a /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT`
4. Type `sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/bootx64.efi`

If that doesn't work, please edit your question to include the output of the following commands:

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
sudo find /boot/efi -iname "*.efi"
```

Comment: i haven't tried it, as i already found the solution above, though i am sure many will follow your post. thank you.