# Can't boot into Live USB, though secure boot has been disabled

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, uefi

- The installation is being carried out alongside Windows 10.
- UEFI is enabled
- Secure boot is disabled
- Live USB works fine on other PCs
- The UBUNTU Iso checksum has been verified too
- Fast boot and hibernate are also disabled

Each time I try to restart the PC with the boot preference having Live USB at the top, I get nothing but Windows starts to load. Please help me fix this.

EDIT 1: The laptop is Acer Aspire 5, with 4gigs of memory, 1 TB of HDD, Nvidia MX940, Intel Core i5 6200u

EDIT 2: I was able to boot through the F12 boot menu finally and also succesfully installed Ubuntu. But now I have a bigger problem. Grub is not loading, neither is it showing in the bios boot menu!

Comment: This could be a specific problem to your computer's brand/model. Please add you them to your answer.

Comment: @EskanderBejaoui I added the computer model. Please tell is it possible to change uefi to legacy first, install ubuntu and then restart and again enable uefi and secure boot.

Comment: I had a hunch it was an Acer, well there are similar cases in this site, I'll link a few of them for you to check and hope you can solve your issue: [Acer Aspire V3 does not recognize my EFI partition](https://askubuntu.com/q/674749/810348), [Allowing boot of Ubuntu on a Acer Aspire v5-531 with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/q/519610/810348), [Bootable device not found after clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/q/597213/810348)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have an Acer Aspire E5 and had the same problem. Follow these steps:

They assume that you are installing Ubuntu, but might also be required for booting from a Live USB

1. Make sure your UEFI is up to date.
2. In UEFI, you must set a supervisor password. Once the supervisor password is set, some new menus are accessible.
3. Enter the "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" menu. It will allow you to declare the newly installed Ubuntu boot image as trusted on your laptop.
4. Select EMMC >> EFI >> Ubuntu and select the file shimx64.efi. You will be prompted to give it a name of your choice (which will appear in the F12 boot options).
5. Type the name press Enter and then "Yes" should be highlighted.
6. Press enter again. Restart the computer without any boot disk and tap F12 during the boot process.
7. You should now get the boot option menu with the name you chose.
8. You can change the boot order in UEFI now so that it boots directly to the Grub screen.
9. Either disable the supervisor password, or save it in a secure place.

Comment: It really works. I did not select UEFI as trusted earlier. Now I have added ubuntu to boot preference 1 and am running it.