# Installing Ubuntu (UEFI)

Tags: system-installation, uefi, windows-8

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04, but I don't know how. I tried many times in the past without success.

I have Windows 8.1 Pro Build 9600 (the PC came with Windows 10 Home). I have an Aspire GX-281 motherboard. My BIOS mode is UEFI and my BIOS version is R01-A4. I have a Ryzen 1400 quad core processor, 3200Mhz 4 cores, 8 logical processors. My graphics card is a GTX 1060 3GB.

I don't think I want to leave Windows 8.1 on my computer, so I guess I'll install Ubuntu as my main OS.

In the past I had these problems.

1. Failed to Load some files on Ubuntu Live-Server / Installing
2. Once the installer finished, it didn't give me the boot option (dual boot).

Here are the images with supervisor password set:

Boot Option:

[image: Boot Option]

Security:

[image: Security]

Authentication:

[image: Authentication]

Ubuntu Error:

[image: Ubuntu Error]

Just in case you can't read the error:

```
[    0.391963] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
[    0.429425] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resources [mem 0xbcb9f000-0xbcb9ffff]
```

I updated the BIOS (R01-A1 To R01-A4), and i checked the SSD firmware (no update needed).

Comment: I think that you want Ubuntu Desktop (not Ubuntu Server). A server has only text screen (no graphical desktop environment) and serves other computers with files etc. The nvidia graphics card means that you need the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` for the graphics to work in the beginning. After the installation you can install an nvidia proprietary driver and get the full power of the graphics card. [This link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) should get you started with the installation.

Comment: [Here](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu/) is how to overwrite Windows and install Ubuntu. Since you have an Acer you might need to follow the steps in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062418/cant-boot-into-live-usb-though-secure-boot-has-been-disabled/1062530#1062530). This is because Acer has a unique feature in BIOS/UEFI. Also follow the above advice from sudodus.

Comment: @sudodus no, i do install desktop environment and it does have a graphical desktop environment. The first error happens when i click install ubuntu/try ubuntu

Comment: Most Acer are similar. You do need to update UEFI, and if SSD update firmware on SSD. After install, you typically have to set "trust" on the Ubuntu entry in UEFI. Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: So, i put the supervisor password, but **"Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"** wasn't there

Comment: Can you take a picture of the screen after you enter a supervisor password and edit it into your post?

Comment: Here you go. Edited the post. I uploaded **Boot Options**, **Security** and **Authentication**

Comment: Did you try with 'nomodeset` yet (or 'recovery mode')?

Comment: You can also try with `rmmod tpm` in the grub menuentry (in order to disable tpm, which is one of the problems). The system *might* be able to live with the initramfs unpacking error. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#Menuentry_Example). Don't apply the whole menuentry, only see how to add a line with `rmmod tpm`

Comment: Just a question (I never used linux before). Is this the menuentry? `boot/grub/grub.cfg` `menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
 set gfxpayload=keep
 linux /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
 initrd /casper/initrd
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu (safe graphics)" {
 set gfxpayload=keep
 linux /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity quiet splash nomodeset ---
 initrd /casper/initrd
}` I know it's written clearly, but just to be sure since the directory etc. does not exist.

Comment: Edit: I downloaded Ubuntu 19.10 and `Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed` didn't show up. However the TPM problem is still present even after setting rmmod tpm in menuentry

Comment: Yes, it is a menuentry: `menuentry "Install Ubuntu" { ... }`. I have no Acer computer, so I cannot help with details about it. Please look into the **details of the links in the comment by oldfred**. You can also send an alert to him by including @oldfred into a comment and maybe get some more details.

Comment: So, another edit (I'm getting sick trying of install ubuntu): I installed the 19.10 version. The tpm_crb didn't go away, but the installation was successful. Now, i added a **Swap Area of 16GB (I have 8GB of RAM), and the other to the OS (ext4 /) **.The SSD is divided in two parts, so Ubuntu is there. But now i don't know how to  select a UEFI file trusted for executing, because the BIOS don't have that option.

Comment: The links above show examples. You have to set UEFI password to get additional setting. Some newer Acer use control S to get settings. Acer Swift 5 (2019) ctrl-s  in UEFI required to be able to change to AHCI mode.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Anyways guys, i installed Ubuntu 19.10 successfully. Thanks y'all for the help. I used EasyBCD. Even if it wasn't suppose to work (Many features are disabled if your BIOS mode is UEFI) ubuntu show up in the **Edit Boot Menu**.